# Why does bidirectional LSTM have half the parameter count compared to LSTM in keras?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, lstm, rnn, parameter

I want to implement a unidirectional and a bidirectional LSTM in tensorflow keras wrapper with the **same amount of units**. As an example I implement the unidirectional LSTM with 256 units, and the bidirectional LSTM with 128 units (which as I understand gives me 128 for each direction, for a total of 256 units). The implementation details:

```
import tensorflow as tf
in_ = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28,28))

x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256)(in_)

model_unidirectional = tf.keras.Model(in_,x)
print(model_unidirectional.summary())

y = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128))(in_)

model_bidirectional = tf.keras.Model(in_,y)
print(model_bidirectional.summary())
```

However, looking at the models' summary, the unidirectional LSTM has double the parameter count compared to the bidirectional LSTM, even if they have the same output shape in both cases:

`model_unidirectional` summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_11 (InputLayer)        [(None, 28, 28)]          0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_11 (LSTM)               (None, 256)               291840    
=================================================================
Total params: 291,840
Trainable params: 291,840
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

`model_bidirectional` summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_11 (InputLayer)        [(None, 28, 28)]          0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_7 (Bidirection (None, 256)               160768    
=================================================================
Total params: 160,768
Trainable params: 160,768
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Why does the bidirectional approach have significantly less parameters if their output shape is the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Unidirectional LSTM the number of parameters are
4*[(numHiddenUnit+inputSize)*numHuddenUnits+numHuddenUnits]

where 4 is for 4 LSTM gate equations.
For your case numHuddenUnits = 256, inputSize is 28 gives the result 291840

For birectional LSTM the number of parameters are
2 * 4 * [(numHiddenUnit+inputSize)*numHuddenUnits+numHuddenUnits]

where 2 is due to bi-directional weights and 4 is for four gate equations

For your case numHuddenUnits = 128, inputSize = 28 gives the result 160768

Answer (score 0):

It's because you wrote:

```
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256)(in_)
```

and:

```
y = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128))(in_)
```

The number of parameters is different: 256 vs 128. Their output shape is the same because Bidirectional RNN layers are technically couples of paired RNN layers.